# R: display (g)lm fit as colour coded image / contour plot

Tags: r, contour, scatter-plot, lm, levelplot

I am on the lookout for a function in R that would display a bivariate (general) linear model fit (`fit=lm(z~x+y)`) as a `levelplot` or `contourplot`, whereby the fitted values as well as the actual data points are colour coded.

The final result I would be looking for would be something like this
(made this one in Mathematica, but I am looking for an R solution now)

[image]

Does anybody have any idea whether there is already a function out there somewhere that does something like this?

EDIT: in the meantime I found a solution - see below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not good form to answer one's own question, but just discovered function `image.lm()` and `contour.lm()` in package `rsm` which plots the fit of a linear model as an image or contour plot, which is what I was looking for. Building on that, I made the following function which plots the result of a (general) linear model fit as a function of two explanatory variables as an image or contour plot, together with the actual data points, using a syntax similar to `plotPlane` in package `rockchalk` (the mean value is used for any variables not in the model):

```
plotImage=function(model=NULL,plotx=NULL,ploty=NULL,plotPoints=T,plotContours=T,plotLegend=F,npp=1000,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,zlab=NULL,xlim=NULL,ylim=NULL,pch=16,cex=1.2,lwd=0.1,col.palette=NULL) {
      library(rockchalk)
      library(aqfig)
      library(colorRamps)
      mf=model.frame(model);emf=rockchalk::model.data(model)
      if (is.null(xlab)) xlab=plotx
      if (is.null(ylab)) ylab=ploty
      if (is.null(zlab)) zlab=names(mf)[[1]]
      if (is.null(col.palette)) col.palette=rev(colorRampPalette(rainbow(13,s=0.9,v=0.8),bias=0.6,interpolate ="spline")(1000))
      x=emf[,plotx];y=emf[,ploty];z=mf[,1]
      if (is.null(xlim)) xlim=c(min(x)*0.95,max(x)*1.05)
      if (is.null(ylim)) ylim=c(min(y)*0.95,max(y)*1.05)
      preds=predictOMatic(model,predVals=c(plotx,ploty),n=npp,divider="seq")
      zpred=matrix(preds[,"fit"],npp,npp)
      zlim=c(min(c(preds$fit,z)),max(c(preds$fit,z)))
      par(mai=c(1.2,1.2,0.5,1.2),fin=c(6.5,6))
      graphics::image(x=seq(xlim[1],xlim[2],len=npp),y=seq(ylim[1],ylim[2],len=npp),z=zpred,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,col=col.palette,useRaster=T,xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
      if (plotContours) graphics::contour(x=seq(xlim[1],xlim[2],len=npp),y=seq(ylim[1],ylim[2],len=npp),z=zpred,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,add=T,method="edge")
      if (plotPoints) {cols1=col.palette[(z-zlim[1])*999/diff(zlim)+1]
                       pch1=rep(pch,length(n))
                       cols2=adjustcolor(cols1,offset=c(-0.3,-0.3,-0.3,1))
                       pch2=pch-15
                       points(c(rbind(x,x)),c(rbind(y,y)), cex=cex,col=c(rbind(cols1,cols2)),pch=c(rbind(pch1,pch2)),lwd=lwd) }
      box()
      if (plotLegend) vertical.image.legend(zlim=zlim,col=col.palette) # TO DO: add z axis label, maybe make legend a bit smaller?
    }

# simulate some data
n=10000
age=rnorm(n,mean=40,sd=5)
height=rnorm(n,mean=180,sd=7)
weight=-85+0.8*age+0.004*height^2+rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=7)
bmi=weight/((height/100)^2)
sbp=33+1.8*age+2.1*bmi-0.035*age*bmi+rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=5)
mydata=data.frame(cbind(age,height,weight,bmi,sbp))


fit1=lm(sbp~age*bmi,data=mydata)
plotImage(fit1,plotx="age",ploty="bmi",plotContours=F,plotLegend=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For irregularly spaced points, I wrote colPoints. 
If anyone knows a good final package for it, please tell me!

```
install.packages("berryFunctions")
library(berryFunctions)
?colPoints

i <- c( 22,  40,  80,  45,  60,  63,  30,  70,  55,  48,  32,  48,  70,  40)
j <- c(  5,  33,  12,  56,  20,  40,  45,  45,  30,  36,  23,  15,  30,  10)
k <- c(175, 174, 120, 105, 132, 130, 190, 110, 131, 160, 183, 163, 117, 168)

mod <- lm(k~i+j)
modcoord <- expand.grid(i=seq(20,80, 0.1), j=seq(0,60,0.1))
modvals <- predict(mod, newdata=modcoord)

colPoints(modcoord$i, modcoord$j, modvals, pch=15, add=FALSE)
colPoints(i,j,k, cex=1.5)
points(i,j, cex=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Ha that's not bad - many thanks for this! One thing that could be worth improving is to add a fine black line around the points (as otherwise well-fitting points won't show up), and maybe to use a gradient fill for the individual small rectangles, maybe using http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/plotrix/html/gradient.rect.html, to make it look smoother. What do you reckon?

Comment: Ha and I also just notice that your function only works if you use a 1:1 aspect ratio - in my R Studio plot window I get white vertical bars showing up...

Comment: What would be the way to make your grid/mesh finer actually? I tried with breaks=1000, but that doesn't seem to do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make more points with expand.grid(i=seq(20,80, 0.1), j=seq(0,60,0.1)). That should also solve the "jagged" appearance issue. You can also take a look at image(t(yourMatrix)) for plotting the matrix without space between the square points (which is creating the white lines).
And add points(i,j, cex=1.5, lwd=2) for lines around the points

Comment: Thanks a lot - that should do it!! I'l have a try here - thanks again for your help!

Comment: I now edited my answer acccordingly. Feel free to mark it as the solving answer ;-)

Comment: Many thanks - I'll! I also just discovered the function image() in package rsm which plots a lm fit as a contour or image plot, which was in fact exactly what I was looking for. I'll also post that as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would look better if you fit a model for z as a polynomial function of x and y:

```
 yourdata <- data.frame(
          "x" = c(22, 40, 80, 45, 60,  63, 30, 70, 55, 48, 32, 48, 70, 40),
          "y" = c(5, 33, 12, 56, 20, 40, 45, 45, 30, 36, 23, 15, 30, 10),
          "z" = c(175, 174, 120, 105, 132, 130, 190, 110, 131, 160, 183, 163, 117, 168) )

fit <- lm(z ~ poly(x, y, degree = 2), data = yourdata)
```

Then plot:

```
library(rsm)
image(fit, y ~ x)
contour(fit, y ~ x)
persp(fit, y ~ x, zlab = "z")
```

The results will show a curved surface rather than a flat plane.

Using ggplot:

```
# ggplots
library(rsm)
SurfMod <- contour(fit, y ~ x)

# extract matrix values from rsm contour
Xvals <- SurfMod$`x ~ y`[1]
Yvals <- SurfMod$`x ~ y`[2]
Zvals <- SurfMod$`x ~ y`[3]

# form matrix with col and row names 
SurfMatrix <- Zvals$z
colnames(SurfMatrix) <- Yvals$y
rownames(SurfMatrix) <- Xvals$x

# Convert matrix to data frame
library(reshape2)
SurfDF <- melt(SurfMatrix)

library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
gg <- ggplot(data = SurfDF) +
  geom_tile(data = SurfDF, aes(Var1, Var2,z = value, fill = value)) +
  stat_contour(data = SurfDF, aes(Var1, Var2, z = value, color = ..level..)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "brown", high = "red") +
  geom_point(data = testdata, aes(x, y, z = z, color = z)) +
  geom_text(data = testdata, aes(x, y,label=z),hjust=0, vjust=0) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")
direct.label.ggplot(gg, "angled.endpoints")
```

For more direct.label plotting methods go to http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/index.html